# How to C# ComboBox edit focus transfer to DataGridview Cell

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, ado.net, window

How to transfer ComboBox edit focus to datagridview cell when i press the ctrl+N for new cell.when i Press ctrl+N my edit focus on comboBox month...Please Help me.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please reword your question and add more description.

Comment: Sorry Dear, i got it..........:) just keyPreview property make true in window form Properties...

Comment: thanks for this next time i post the questions in details..........